# Как сохранить данные с формы в базу данных используя ajax/jquery?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

Подскажите реальное решение, как безопасно сохранять данные с формы в базу данных и выводить эти данные в админке сайта? Плюсом будет параллельно слать данные и на мыло тоже.

Можно на Wordpress, Joomla - можно и без.

Пробовал на Joomla с ChronoForms5 - все работало норм без включения ajax (в настройках ChronoForms). Как только включаю ajax - перестает отправлять письмо и сохранять в БД.

Нашел интересный плагин к Wordpress - [Contact Form DB](http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/contact-form-7-to-database-extension). В описании к нему [вычитал](http://cfdbplugin.com/?page_id=508), что он может работать напрямую с html-формами (а не теми, что созданы в wordpress'e, типа contact form 7).
Но пока так и не удалось его заставить работать с моей формой.

Создал тему на форуме модуля (там можно подробнее глянуть весь мой код):
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-use-this-plugin-with-custom-html-form-with-ajax-and-jquery?replies=1#post-8097290

Моя форма в HTML

```
<form id="f2" action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="ФИО" maxlength="50" required>
  <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" maxlength="50" required>
  <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Телефон" maxlength="50" required>
  <input type="text" name="org" placeholder="Учебное заведение" maxlength="50" required>
  <button class="btn" type="submit">Отправить</button>
</form>
```

JS обработчик

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//...
$("form#f2").submit(function() {

var form = $(this),
  name = form.find("input[name='wpname']").val(),
  email = form.find("input[name='wpemail']").val(),
  phone = form.find("input[name='wpphone']").val(),
  org = form.find("input[name='wporg']").val();

if (!name || !email || !phone || !org) {
  alert("Заполните поля формы.");
  return false;
}

var email_regexp = /.+@.+\..+/i;
var email_test = email_regexp.test(email);
if (!email_test) {
  alert("Введен некоректный Email-адрес.");
  return false;
}

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "wp-content/themes/epixx/mail.php",
  data: $("form#f2").serialize(),
  success: function(response) {
    $(".order_status").show();
    $("form#f1").hide();
    $("form#f2").hide();
    console.log('response: ' + response);
  },
  error:  function(xhr, str){
    alert('Возникла ошибка: ' + xhr.responseCode);
  }
}).done(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $.fancybox.close();
  }, 2000);
});
return false;
  });
});
```

и мой mail.php

```
<?php

$recepient = "test@gmail.com";
$sitename = "TEST";

$name = trim($_POST["wpname"]);
$email = trim($_POST["wpemail"]);
$phone = trim($_POST["wpphone"]);
$org = trim($_POST["wporg"]);

$pagetitle = "Новая заявка с сайта \"$sitename\"";
$message = "Имя: $name\r\nEmail: $email\r\nТелефон: $phone\r\nУчебное заведение: $org";
mail($recepient, $pagetitle, $message, "Content-type: text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\"$EOL From: $name <$email>");

/* contact-form-7-to-database */
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7-to-database-extension/CFDBShortCodeSavePostData.php');
$handler = new CFDBShortCodeSavePostData;
$handler->handleShortcode(null);
```

Вот что выдает ajax response:

```
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  require_once(ABSPATHwp-content/plugins/contact-form-7-to-database-extension/CFDBShortCodeSavePostData.php) [<a href='function.require-once'>function.require-once</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in <b>/var/www/u0081082/public_html/donkon.ru/devwp/wp-content/themes/epixx/mail.php</b> on line <b>16</b><br />
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  require_once() [<a href='function.require'>function.require</a>]: Failed opening required 'ABSPATHwp-content/plugins/contact-form-7-to-database-extension/CFDBShortCodeSavePostData.php' (include_path='.:') in <b>/var/www/u0081082/public_html/donkon.ru/devwp/wp-content/themes/epixx/mail.php</b> on line <b>16</b><br />
```

Ссылка на проект в сети: donkon.ru/devwp

Comment: на Joomla по умолчанию грузится библиотека `noconflict`, грузится отсюда: `ваш сайт/media/jui/js/jquery-noconflict.js`, при это во всём вашем коде js надо заменить знак `$` на `jQuery`, и всё должно работать (например не `$.ajax({` а `jQuery.ajax({`)

Comment: @Blacknife, в моем случае это проблемы не было точно, т.к. я все скрипты джумлы блокировал нафиг (+ у меня голая (своя) тема). Да и вообще при работе с ChronoForms я свой JS-обработчик отключал тоже. Так что проблема с джумлой была точно не в этом. По компоненту ChronoForms мало инфы в сети просто.. Про WP мне удалось найти больше информации для реализации того, что нужно мне..

Comment: Ну судя по ошибке которую ты добавил, у тебя неверный путь к `mail.php`, укажи путь к файлу относительно корня сайта, подставив перед ссылкой слэш `url: "/wp-content/themes/epixx/mail.php",`

Comment: также и в файле `mail.php` : `require_once(ABSPATH . '/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7-to-database-extension/CFDBShortCodeSavePostData.php');`

Comment: ну и я никогда не работал с WP конечно, но по-моему константа ABSPATH не будет работать в вашем файле `mail.php` без подключения определённых файлов вордпресс, так-что попробуйте указать относительный путь без этой константы для начала

Comment: @Blacknife, ты прав. Спасибо, за внимание )

Answer (score 2):

Оказываться в WordPress очень неудобно использовать отдельные от него php-скрипты (как мой mail.php).

Я создал функцию send_form() в function.php (лежит в папке с темой) и добавил в неё весь код из моего mail.php. Теперь переменная ABSPATH работает.

ну и в аяксе url заменил на
/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=send_form

И все заработало! ))